# Retrieve friend's name from firebase firestore in functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best way to retrieve my friend's first and last name in Firebase functions? I tried a few ways, but it's not working.

1. Collection of users.
2. Persons_id is autogenerated document id.
3. Friends is an array of objects with persons_id.
4. Name has an object of first and last.

I am making a http request using the document id, and responding with an array of first/last name of my friends.

```
const id = String(req.body.id);
admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(id);

friends = [];
friends.push(jsonObject); // not sure if i should do a for loop
res.send({ friends: friends }); // responding with array
```

Firestore:

```
Users (collection)
"c7xXQC5cEq5JyWyED8rX" (document)
name: {
  first: "John",
  last: "Doe",
},
friends: [ {
  persons_id: "0fLXpei6kEgrCkfFCeJi",
  confirmed: true,
},
  persons_id: "65ghQC5cEq5JyWyED8rX",
  confirmed: false,
} ],
username: "johndoe",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best solution for me was to create a subcollection with friends and populate that with person_id, confirmed, etc. Users collection would still have Firstname, Lastname, etc.

```
Users (collection)
"c7xXQC5cEq5JyWyED8rX" (document)
Friends (collection)
"FadcjWG0GpDgkFujGWaa" (document)
person_id: string -> Users -> document id
confirmed: boolean
```